# how do retrieve date equal or not equal input type date .value and from database date column in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, .net, .net-framework-version

i wanna retrieve input type date from database date column,how can i do that
and i wanna database date column doesn't exist or not equal dont show data

IN HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
    <label for="start">Günün Menüsü için Tarih Seçiniz:</label>

    <input type="date" runat="server" id="datee" name="trip-start"
           value="2018-07-22"
           min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
</div>
```

IN aspx.cs

```
if (datee.Value.ToString() == "Tarih".ToString())
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server=.;Database=MerkezCafeDB;Integrated Security = True";
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from GununMenusu", conn);
            DataTable datatbl = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(datatbl);
            Repeater2.DataSource = datatbl;
            Repeater2.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
            
        }
        else
        {
            
        }
```

btw sorry for my bad eng

Comment: How can an input date that is being sent to the server have the value `"Tarih"`?

Comment: `"Tarih"`is database date column name

Comment: But your input date `datee` has a date value when it's sent to the server and you're comparing it with that string. That `if` condition will never be satisfied. Or am I missing something?

Comment: not missing but am i wrong ? i just dont wanna type error bcs i do that